# Working around JMS MessageConsumer.receive(long) not returning within the timeout

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

`MessageConsumer.receive(long)` allows specifying a timeout on the receive.

However, I have found that if you make the producer go away (e.g. by killing the process), the receive on the consumer doesn't *always* time out. In fact, sometimes it waits forever and the process never exits.

It turns out that I can add an `ExceptionListener` to the connection, but this has some drawbacks:
(1) I might get errors about things other than the operation I was trying to perform;
(2) receive() itself still won't necessarily complete;
(3) Apparently we used to use an ExceptionListener and it was causing some other issues which I don't know the specifics of.

One potential hack which looks viable for us (we're using ActiveMQ) is that when the stall occurs, the thread will be in wait() (this is almost certainly implementation-specific but it seems like it would be a common choice.) So if we got an exception, we could interrupt the thread doing the receive() calls.

Is this a sane solution? Is there a more reliable, well-known, commonly-implemented workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using receive, you could setup a message listener.  This seems like a bug in ActiveMQ, have you reported it as an issue in their JIRA?

Comment: No, I haven't... I wasn't sure enough that it was a bug to report it, because the entire JMS API is so wishy-washy about all details of behaviour that almost anything would be considered to be following the documented behaviour...

Comment: Returning within the expected amount of time is clearly defined by the spec.  I would strongly recommend that if you see an implementer not following that a bug be raised with them.